# Retrieving a value from a called function

Tags: python, function, return, call

I'm using *Python3.*

Let's say we have four functions, `a, b, c` and `d`. Now assume that the callstack is as following:

`a` calls `b`, which calls `c`, which calls `d`. Function `d` calculates a parameter `x` which is needed later on in function `a`, but other than that, `x` is completely irrelevant for `b` and `c`.

My question is, what is the best way to "get" the variable `x` to function `a`. Intuitively, I'd say that I could let all the functions return `x` too, and that way `x` becomes accessible in function `a`. However, this feels so "bad" because the parameter `x` is completely irrelevant for the other functions. Could I potentially work with pointers maybe? I just want to know the most professional way to solve such a case.

Comment: Try it out, and show us your attempt and then we can help you.

Comment: Perhaps you could you assign x to a global variable ? Although, depending on the context this could be anything from a great idea to a terrible one...

Comment: `a` didn't call `d` directly so if we can assume that `b` and `c` did something necessary for `d`, they already know they are intermediate functions and propagating their work back would be okay. if these things are all fairly highly coupled, they could all be part of a class, implementing different bits.

Comment: U need to explain better

Comment: "this feels so "bad" because the parameter x is completely irrelevant for the other functions" If it really is, this often points to a problem with how work is divided between the functions. It's hard to advise without a real example.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to magically pass values between functions. A couple options are:

- The intermediate functions take `x` from the previous one just to return it
- The intermediate functions take an extra parameter which can store `x` and then `d` fills it.
- `x` is calculated in `a` and passed to `b`, `c`, and `d` so that `d` can use it.
- All of those functions are methods of a class which would store `x` as a property, since properties are accessible to all of the methods.

All of these, though, are "bad" practice like you felt. As many of the comments said, there is probably a better way to separate the code between the functions so that you don't have to share that value. Without a more concrete example, no one can really help you here, but some possibilities are:

- Flatten the call graph so that `a` calls all of the other functions directly; then `d` can return`x` directly to `a`
- If `x` is easy / cheep to calculate, just calculate it twice for `a` and `d` separately (and maybe have a separate function to calculate it)
- Move the code from`a` that uses `x` into `d`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have the function `d` assign the value to a member variable `x` of the function `a`:

```
def a():
  ... # some work
  b()
  print('x =', a.x)

def b():
  ... # some work
  c()

def c():
  ... # some work
  d()

def d():
  ... # some work
  a.x = 5 # make the value 5 available to the function `a` through the member variable `x`

a()
```

Output:

```
x = 5
```